# Syntax and semantics of symbol characters in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell.

One of my standard techniques when learning a new language is to implement a Hello World genetic algorithm that attempts to generate a string via genetic algorithm techniques that matches some input string.

Due to my inexperience with Haskell (the closest thing I have to compare is Kotlin) I searched for an example code so I could match my existing understanding of basic genetic algorithm to the code and intuit some understanding of Haskell based on my already underway reading/research on the language.

I came across this tutorial: https://www.arcadianvisions.com/blog/2011/haskell-genetic-algorithm-hello-world.html

I transcribed it in atom after setting my environment up, each part I didn't understand I did a quick google, if I didn't understand the syntax/semantics after 15 minutes I would carry on transcribing with the intent to catch up later on those particular parts.

So, I understood most of the code, such as the order of function application, monads (think I'm nearly there with monads anyway), data types, function types, currying, type substitution etc. However, there were several bits of syntax/semantics that I haven't seen in my reading/researching and not sure what they do, but they appear a lot in the code example I linked to above. I'm hoping someone can explain them to me:

```
(++)
(:)
<$>
<*>
(,)
(x !!)
p@(info@())
```

I am assuming the `()` and `<>` are some special syntax and the stuff inside them is semantic? When I hover over them in atom (I'm using atom-haskell-ghc) I can see the type `Functor f => Applicative (f :: * -> *) where <*> :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` which kind of looks like a monad, but I don't really understand the weird syntax/semantics on the consuming end. Should I think of these as just another function (with a weird infix alias?).

Here is a specific line exhibiting several of the examples from above:

```
mate :: RandomGen g => Gene -> Gene -> Rand g Gene
mate gene1 gene2 = (++) <$> flip take gene1 <*> flip drop gene2 <$> pivot
  where pivot = getRandomR (0, length gene1 - 1)
```

Comment: The Haskell wiki has an overview of some, https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords the others are functions you can lookup with *hoogle*: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28%2B%2B%29

Comment: Yea, I have hoogle setup so I can do lookup through the terminal. I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, hat hoogle link says the (++) performs list concatenation. I thought ++ did that... are the parenthesis just redundant? Hang on I will post actual code with bit I don't understand.

Comment: No parenthesis are not redundant, `(++)` is the function that concatenates. But you can use such functions as operators, so `(++) x y == x ++ y`.

Comment: Ah, so actually the x ++ y is the infix variation of the (++) x y?

I actually prefer the (++) x y variant as it will keep consistent with what I already learned/wrote in haskell. Is there a "standard" way which people prefer to write - infix or not?

Comment: well there is no *Official Haskell language court*" that will put you in jail for using one syntax over another :). I think usually by defining an operator of the sort `(?)` (here `?` is can be any sequence of symbols), it hints more towards infix use, but since you do not per se add all parameters to a function, you can for instance use them as a part of other functions, like for instance `zipWith (++) [[1], [4]], [[2], [5]]`.

Comment: but some agree :) https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2003-July/012260.html

Comment: Lol yea, you're right, no point getting caught up on infix/prefix, but it is kinda confusing to have to read other peoples code and not know which way they are writing, especially when they are chaining functions?

Comment: “Methinks it is like a weasel?” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are mostly all regular functions.

The `<>` are not special syntax, just part of the function name.

The `()` are regular parenthesis which group things and define precedence like in most other languages, the important note is that when you want to refer to an operator function (like `++`) it must be in parenthesis.

- `++` is the list concatenation function  `[1,2] ++ [3,4] = [1,2,3,4]`, or without using infix notation `(++) [1,2]  [3,4] = [1,2,3,4]`
- `:` is the 'cons' function, it prepends an element to a list `1 : [2, 3, 4] = [1,2,3,4]` or `(:) 1 [2, 3, 4] = [1,2,3,4]` without infix notation.
- `<$>` is an infix operator alias of `fmap`
- `<*>` is the applicative application function
- `,` is the tuple constructor `(,) 1 2 = (1, 2)`
- `!!` is the list index function `[1,2,3] !! 1 = 2`.  Note that since these are singly linked lists, indexing is an O(n) operation.
- `@` is used to define an "as pattern".  When pattern matching it allows you to give a name to a parameter, while also destructuring it with pattern matching.  For example the pattern `f (xs@[x1, x2])` matches a two element list, where you can use `x1` and `x2` to refer to the individual elements and `xs` to refer to the list as a whole

Comment: Yup, this is the answer. In addition to what Willem Van Onsem said this make sense now. It's blowing my mind that you can use  `<$>` or `<PinkFairy>` or `<HarryPoter>` as function names. So, () used for precedence (like maths or boolean logic), `!!` is indexing, `@` is patterns, and every other symbol is up for grabs? `<*~~LM>> foo :: Int ->` Int :P

Comment: Not exactly. In Haskell, an indentifier can either be a function name, then probably only single-quote is allowed on top of usual alnum-underscore, or an operator, then it consists of operator symbols, like `<**>`. You should switch to Lisp if you want a real naming madness, where - is used in the names to separate words instead of camelCase, and + and - are usual plain identifiers.

Answer (score 7):

## A note on operators

In Haskell you can define a function that has as identifier a sequence of symbols wrapped between brackets, like for example `(++)` or `(:)` that is an *operator* that can be used both as a function, like `(++) x y`, and as an infix operator, like `x ++ y`. Behind the curtains, the Haskell compiler will convert the infix operator to a function call, so `x ++ y` is completely equivalent with `(++) x y` (except for the fact that operators have different precedence rules).

## `(++)`

This is the *append* function: [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) it takes two lists as input, and constructs a list of the same type of elements that contains the elements of the first list followed by the elements of the second list. For example:

```
(++) [1, 4, 2, 5] [1, 3, 0, 2] == [1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2]
```

## `(:)`

This is a *constructor* of the list type `[a]`. It has type **`(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`**. It takes as input an element and a list of elements (all of the same type), it construct a list that starts with the first element, followed by the elements of the second parameter. For example:

```
(:) 1 [4, 2, 5] = [1, 4, 2, 5]
```

## `(<$>)`

You wrote in your question `<$>`, but as you perhaps figured out, that means that somewhere a function [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-) is defined.

A `Functor` is a typeclass. Several types in Haskell are functors. The easiest ones are a list `[]`, and a `Maybe`. The `(<$>)` takes as input a function `f :: a -> b`, and a functor instance, for example a list `[a]`. It will then convert it to a functor instance `[b]`. How this is done, depends on how the `Functor` instance is implemented (the `(<$>)` for a `Maybe` has different semantics than one for `[]`).

Although the analogy is not complete, you can see a `Functor` sometimes as a collection of elements (a `Maybe` basically is a collection of zero `Nothing`, or one `Just x` elements). It will then map the elements the collection contains by channeling these through the function, for example:

```
(+1) <$> [1, 4, 2, 5] == [2, 5, 3, 6]
(+1) <$> Nothing == Nothing
(+1) <$> (Just 2) == Just 3
```

## `(<*>)`

This function [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) is again somewhat hard to understand. It makes use of an `Applicative` type class.

An type that is an instance of `Applicative` has to implement two functions: `pure :: Applicative a => a -> f a` and `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` (or the programmer can decide to instead implement `liftA2`, but let us ignore that here).

Again you can see `Applicative` (at least for popular instances) as a collection (like `[]` or `Maybe`). Here we thus take as input such collection of functions (all with type `a -> b`), and a collection of `a`s. We then "multiply" these, in the sense that for instance for a list:

```
   [f1, f2, ..., fm] <*> [x1, x2, ..., xn]
== [f1 x1, f1 x2, ..., f1 xn,
    f2 x1, f2 x2, ..., f2 xn,
    ...,
    fm x1, fm x2, ..., fm xn]
```

So that means for instance for `Maybe` that if the left operand is `Nothing`, or the right operand is `Nothing`, or both are `Nothing`, then this results in a `Nothing`, if both are `Just`s (so `Just f <*> Just x`), then we obtain a `Just (f x)`:

```
Just f <*> Just x == Just (f x)
Just f <*> Nothing == Nothing
Nothing <*> Just x == Nothing
Nothing <*> Nothing == Nothing
```

## `(,)`

This is the constructor of a *2-tuple*: **`(,) :: a -> b -> (a,b)`** thus takes as input an `a` and a `b`, and it constructs an 2-tuple where the first item is the first parameter, and the second item is the second parameter. For example:

```
(,) 4 'a' == (4, 'a')
```

## `(x !!)`

This is a [*section of an infix operator*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator). You can use an infix operator, and for instance specify the left or the right part. In that case you thus construct a partially applied function. For example:

```
([1, 4, 2, 5] !!) == (!!) [1, 4, 2, 5]
(!! 2) == flip (!!) 2
```

So for the latter it thus means that we constructed a function that takes as input a parameter that will be filled in as left operand. So:

```
(!! 2) [1, 4, 2, 5] == (!!) [1, 4, 2, 5]
```

The [**`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) function takes as input a list and an `Int` and it returns the element at that index (zero-based indices).

## `p@(info@())`

In contrast to the above, the `@` is *not* a function or operator (well these are actually the same), but a [**keyword**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.40).

It is used in pattern matching to obtain a reference to both an pattern and for instance match subpatterns (or obtain references to subpatterns).

For instance, say we want to pattern match a 2-tuple, and we want to have a reference to the entire tuple, and the first element, we can use:

```
somefunction total@(left, _) = ...
```

So if we then call `somefunction (4, 'a')`, then this means that `total` will hold `(4, 'a')`, and `left` will hold `4`.